# Sound volume randomly changes

Tags: audio

I'll be listening to music or a podcast, when for no reason that I can tell, the sound will sometimes change. Fortunately, it seems to always go down, not get super loud and blow out my ears.

This happens in any and every audio program, so I don't think it's app specific.

I'm using Android 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy S2. The phone is rooted.

How do I prevent the sound from making random adjustments?

Comment: This issue seems to have been corrected by upgrading to a kernel and ROM which are more compatible with my hardware. Should I put that as an answer or should the question be closed?

Comment: I would put that as an answer and mark it as such since that was the solution for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away after I installed a kernel and ROM that was developed more specifically for my particular phone, the SC-02C.

The lesson learned was to be really sure before rooting or upgrading that one is working with the exact right ROM and kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Many others have had this problem and have overcome it by loading the [Persist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netroken.android.persistfree) app from Google Play:

> Audio management made easy - Persist puts you in complete control of your audio with a variety of volume controls and settings.
>
> - Presets
> - **Volume Locker - Prevent volume changes**
> - Silent and vibrate modes
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, I have tried this app for the last few hours and have discovered that it does not prevent the volume from making spontaneous changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung 42" volume uncontrollable and the red power light flickers. This might not be for everyone, before replacing it with a new one I sprayed the on-off switch for a few days. Each day it improved now I have no problem.
                                                 Sonny

Comment: I used contact cleaner which should not harm components.

Answer (score 0):

Had problem with volume changing sporadically and interrupted by Google doing voice search.

After trying to shut down Google searches, etc., And failing, ended up switching earbuds to newer pair. That seemed to work.

Still would like option to shut off Google, maybe in another release of android. None of the soluions offered worked with my phone and android 7.